# Инспекция кода. Парсер для сайта. Задание на позицию Junior

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, задание-на-собеседовании

Доброго времени суток!

Прошу Вашей помощи. Попробовал себя в задании на позицию Junior'a в одну компанию.

Задание было следующее:

Написать парсер, который соберет с сайта отзывы клиентов. В следующей форме:
Имя_Отзыв_Дата.

Сам парсер я сделал, код работает, отзывы собирает, и казалось бы все супер, и я скоро получу таки работу, но - пришел отказ. Само собой - причину мне не объяснили. Если вдруг у Вас будет время, посмотрите пожалуйста код.

Безусловно, там есть костыли, без которых я увы, не могу, не имеючи опыта работы. Хотелось бы получить анализ в ЦЕЛОМ. Может я вообще не так всё делаю.

Прошу критиковать. Спасибо!

Я понимаю, что тут код читать тяжело, на всякий случай, я дам ссылку на гитхаб.

[Вот тут](https://github.com/fer0m/parser_bookmaker_ratings.ru/blob/master/Parsing_bookmaker.py)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

def init_driver():
    path = "C:\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    driver.get("https://bookmaker-ratings.ru/review/obzor-bukmekerskoj-kontory-ligastavok/all-feedbacks/")
    return driver

def how_many_comment():
    # Поиск значения Общего Количества отзывов
    value_with_number = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='tab-nav-item item active']")[0].text

    # Получаем из текста число
    count_comments = int(re.findall('\d+', value_with_number)[0])
    return count_comments

# Функция парса информации, с возможностью назначение количества необходимых отзывов вручную
def copy_func(comment_count):
    total_result = []
    try:
        # Запуск цикла "пробега" по отзывам
        for i in range(1, comment_count + 1):
            # Тут теле if - лютый велописед для прогрузки последующих отзывов с обходом ошибки ChromeDriver на моей ОС
        if i % 30 == 0:
            time.sleep(5)

            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='menu-scroll']/a[13]").send_keys(Keys.HOME)
                time.sleep(5)
            except:
                pass
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='all-feedbacks-more-btn']").click()
                time.sleep(5)

        try:
            # Получаем необходимую текстовую часть. Имя_Роль, Оценку, Отзыв, Дату отзыва

            # Имя_Роль
            name_and_stats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                "//div[@id='feedbacks-list']/div[" + str(i) + "]/div[@class='head']/div[@class='name']")[0].text

            # Значение оценки
            count = \
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                    "//div[@id='feedbacks-list']/div[" + str(i) + "]/div[1]/span/span[2]")[
                    0].text

            # Сам отзыв
            comment = \
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='feedbacks-list']/div[" + str(i) + "]/div[2]/div[1]")[
                    0].text

            # Дата
            date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='feedbacks-list']/div[" + str(i) + "]/div[3]/div[1]")[
                0].text

            temp_value = name_and_stats.split(' ')

            # Временная функция для извлечения отдельно Имени и Роли.
            stats = temp_value[-1:]
            name = ' '.join(temp_value[:-1])
            total_result.append([name] + stats + [str(count)] + [comment] + [date])

        except:
            pass

    return total_result

except:
    print("Закончили")
    return total_result


# Запись в файл.
def csv_writer(data):
    FILENAME = "Database.csv"
    with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    time.sleep(5)
    csv_writer(copy_func(how_many_comment()))
```

На ровном месте начал получать дизлайки за якобы рекламу сайта в коде
Скрин письма задания : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум, Ваш код не соответствует `PEP-8`. Также я думаю, что использование `Selenium`'а избыточно.

Comment: Попробуй сделать парсинг через библиотеку requests

Comment: @CheekiBreeki И как Вы себе это представляете? :)

Comment: "Само собой - причину мне не объяснили" - это не само собой. Возьмите и спросите, если этого не было в письме об отказе. Прямо спросить, почему именно вам отказали - это вполне нормально.

Comment: это явно реклама - там сайт в парсер #bookmaker#-ratings#ru

Comment: Эм, при всем уважении. Данные сайты кто-то из программистов создаёт и обслуживает, реклама тут не причем. Или это исключено? Ежели ставите минус, скажите что в коде плохо.

Comment: Минусы, это часть работы сайта, не обращайте внимания xD. По крайней мере они появляются очень часто и в 95% случаев поставивший вам не будет объяснять их наличие. Как бы shit happens.

Comment: Не воспринимайте одиночные минусы, это бывает.